# How to Add Max Character Length to the following code

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

```
<td class="field-value">
    @Html.TextBox("SSN", "", new { style = "width:100px" })
</td>
```

Where would I actually place the maxLength property?  Is maxLength the best option here?

Comment: I need the TextBox to only hold 9 characters

Comment: you can check via jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes maxLength would be the best option here.  Simply add it with the rest of your attributes:

> @Html.TextBox("SSN", "", new { style = "width:100px", maxLength = 9
>   })

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure why I couldn't get it to work before.  It was probably a minor syntax error on my part.

Comment: No problem!  I updated the answer to reflect your comment for any future readers.  If the answer satisfied your question please accept the answer for future readers -- thanks